# Linux command or Utility for checking logs about deleted files or directories

Tags: linux, command

How I can check when the particular files or files inside particular directory are deleted in Linux ?

Particular I am using Amazon RHL Server. I tried with
`sudo grep -a 'deleted_file.txt' /home/user1/.bash_history`

this command but it is not giving any result also tried with other users existed on my RHL server, but no results.
Is there any command / utility for that?

Comment: If you want to know when files were deleted in the past, I don't believe there's any tool for that. If you want to actively monitor a directory and see if any files get deleted, take a look at `inotifywait`.

Comment: okay  is `inotifywait` acts as audit tool ? because I am unaware about it . Also by default AWS RHL does not installed this I guess.

Comment: All it can do is tell you if a file has been deleted (or changed, or added) in a given directory. It won't tell you, for example, who deleted it, or why. You need to tell it which directories to monitor. If you want to monitor the entire filesystem, that would be a bit hard to do.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will indeed look into this option.